# Automatically reset api key if sent via unsecured HTTP

Tags: passwords

I have an API where clients authenticate via Http basic auth (account:apikey). Users can generate (and revoke) many apikeys for the same account.

I currently only accept HTTPS requests, but I am toying with the idea of *enabling* HTTP and, upon successful authentication of account:apikey, *automatically disable that apikey* on the basis that it was sent via an unencrypted channel.

Can this scheme improve the security of the authentication in my Api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this would improve the security at all. If your API endpoint does not have port 80/tcp open, nobody will ever be able to start a connection, let alone send API keys to it.

With a closed 80/tcp port, as soon as anyone sends a `SYN` packet to it, the endpoint will answer with a `RST`, the handshake never completes, and no data is sent.

If you have the "expire from HTTP" function at the endpoint, you will have to open another port, listen to authentication, verify the login details are valid, and revoke them. Until the user discovers it accidentally sent data from HTTP, it will frustrate him and forces him to re-login, re-create a key, alter all config files, and restart programming. Without that, and with port 80 closed, the user tries to send data, gets a `connection refused` error, changes port and happily keeps programming.

Comment: I did not think of that, I sort of assumed port 80 would be used to redirect to https. But for API, it makes sense to have the port closed in many applications. That being said, the attacker can answer on port 80, so this has the small disadvantage that a programming error of trying HTTP first may not be caught, if the fallback is https. Or if the HTTP request is not essential for the app. Unlikely scenario, but I just mention it.